# Titanium error "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable"

Tags: android, python, titanium

I'm building a Titanium Application for Android 2.2 Using Titanium SDK 2.0.1.GA2.
I can't resolve this error about TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable.

This is the Errors:

```
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "/home/owner/titanium_sdk/amd64/mobilesdk/linux/2.0.1.GA2/android/builder.py", line 2125, in <module>
[ERROR]     s.build_and_run(True, avd_id, device_args=device_args)
[ERROR]   File "/home/owner/titanium_sdk/amd64/mobilesdk/linux/2.0.1.GA2/android/builder.py", line 1973, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     launched, launch_failed = self.package_and_deploy()
[ERROR]   File "/home/owner/titanium_sdk/amd64/mobilesdk/linux/2.0.1.GA2/android/builder.py", line 1521, in package_and_deploy
[ERROR]     output = run.run([zipalign, '-v', str(ALIGN_32_BIT), app_apk, app_apk+'z'])
[ERROR]   File "/home/owner/titanium_sdk/amd64/mobilesdk/linux/2.0.1.GA2/android/run.py", line 30, in run
[ERROR]     print "[DEBUG] %s" % (subprocess.list2cmdline(args))
[ERROR]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 587, in list2cmdline
[ERROR]     needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
[ERROR] TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I don't use Titanium Studio and I execute builder.py directly for building application.
The application I want to build is created using Titanium SDK 2.0.1.GA2.
I already moved aapt, dx, lib in build-tools 17.0.0 into platform-tools.

This is my development emvironment:

OS: Debian 7 on VMWare Fusion 5.0.3
Python: Python 2.7.3
nodejs: v0.10.33
Java: OpenJDK 1.6

How do I build this one?

Thanks and best regards.